# Excel VBA Data organization with splitting and duplication

Tags: excel, vba

In Microsoft Excel, I am looking to use VBA code to sort through large amounts of data that is not optimally organized

Currently, I have data that looks like this:
[Poor Data Organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3xWS.jpg)[image]

However, I would like to process the data to this:
[Correct Data Organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci5ZF.jpg)[image]

I have been unable to find an example for my specific situation and appreciate your time and responses.

Comment: It's very, very, very rare to find code pre-written that will do exactly what you want.  You almost always have to write something that suits your specific requirements.  Which bit of writing the code are you stuck on?

Comment: Power Query may be a useful tool for Data Cleaning.It's a free add-on before Excel 2016, but is standard in 2016

Comment: You can use `Split(valueHere, vbLf)` on the Col H/J values, then loop over the resulting arrays and repeat the values from the other columns.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: Tim Williams, I have iterated through a few Macros using the split function, however never achieved exactly what I was looking for.

YowE3K, maybe a more clear statement would have been that I couldn't find any examples to help me learn how to write the code that would process my data as required.

As Tim suggested, I attempted the use of the Split function, however I also ran into several examples that using different methods. To answer your question, I am stuck on inexperience and appreciate all input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will process the data into the format you're after.  The source data is in Sheet1 and the reformatted data is placed into Sheet2:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MapCell2Cells()
  Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
  Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

  Dim strG As String, strL As String
  Dim arrH() As String, arrI() As String, arrJ() As String

  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, idx As Integer, lastRow As Integer
  lastRow = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

  idx = 1
  For i = 1 To lastRow:

    With sht1
      strG = Replace(.Cells(i, "G").Value, vbLf, "")
      arrH = Split(.Cells(i, "H").Value, vbLf)
      arrI = Split(.Cells(i, "I").Value, vbLf)
      arrJ = Split(.Cells(i, "J").Value, vbLf)
      strL = Replace(.Cells(i, "L").Value, vbLf, "")
    End With

    With sht2
      For j = LBound(arrH) To UBound(arrH)
        .Cells(idx, "G").Value = strG
        .Cells(idx, "H").Value = arrH(j)
        .Cells(idx, "I").Value = arrI(j)
        .Cells(idx, "J").Value = arrJ(j)
        .Cells(idx, "L").Value = strL
        idx = idx + 1
      Next
    End With

  Next

End Sub
```